# How to use push technology with embedded product using php, javascript, html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, smarty

I am looking to implement push technology with embedded product. can anyone please help me?
Actually I am working on a GUI using php, smart, prototype.js, html, css from where a user of wi-fi product can change the settings on board. and the size of that product is very less only 8MB where we have around 6MB's files already.
Actually every time we are sending the AJAX request to wi-fi board to get the latest information about GPSvalues but sometimes nothing has been changed in board but AJAX requesting to board. So my question is that is there any way that board will let browser know whenever new data is there??
Please reply if you have the answer....

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: is the application you are developing on the Wi-Fi board itself?

Comment: Yes. First writing the code after that making the .tar file and flashing on board. and the .tar file is having all drievers, lighttpd web server and GUI files.

Answer (score 0):

> is that is there any way that board will let browser know whenever new data is there?

Yes, via 304 Response Status

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5